# Multiple JOIN statements returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, join

I believe I need a fresh set of eyes, my attention has been pulled elsewhere at work and I have not had the time to figure this out. So I'm hoping someone may be kind enough to offer a suggestion.

Here is an abbreviated version of my SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
  PR.PROJECTNUM, 
  PR.PROJECTNUMBER, 
  PR.AMRNUM, 
  W.WONUM, 
  C.PONUM, 
  C.POLINENUM 
FROM PROJECT PR

INNER JOIN WORKORDER W

ON PR.PROJECTNUM = W.PROJECTNUM 
  OR PR.PROJECTNUMBER = W.PROJECTNUMBER
  OR PR.AMRNUM = W.AMRNUM

INNER JOIN 

 (SELECT PL.WONUM, P.PONUM, PL.POLINENUM FROM PO P 
   INNER JOIN POLINE PL ON P.PONUM = PL.PONUM) C 

ON W.WONUM = C.WONUM;
```

As you can see, I'm joining 4 tables here.`PO` to `POLINE` to `WORKORDER` to `PROJECT`. The issue lies with the multiple joining attributes between the `WORKORDER` and `PROJECT` table.

I do not know beforehand which attribute/field will be populated with a value in the `WORKORDER` table, but at least one will be...but sometimes all three. The duplication occurs when more than one of the joining attributes in the `WORKORDER` table is populated with a matching value in the `PROJECT` table.

It's almost as if I need to test for the presence of a value in the joining attribute from the `WORKORDER` table before I execute the above SQL....and if more than one is populated with a value, then I need to find which one of the `PROJECT`attributes has a matching value....geez...even typing it out is making my head spin...lol

I may need to come back in the morning and add a little more context, my brain is fried at the moment :)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps you need to use an aggregate query to select one of your results per group.  Sample data and desired results would make this easier to understand though.

Comment: Hmmm...yes, that could work. I'll test it when I get to work. Thanks!